# Необходимость объяснения связей между таблицами MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблици students, parents. 
В студенте поля id, surname, m_id, f_id. В parents id, surname, name.
Суррогатные ключи:  m_id, f_id (parets.id). По логике, у одной записи из родителей может быть несколько записей из студентов (несколько детей). А у студента может быть двезаписи - мама и папа, одна - мама или папа, и вообще ни одной. В таком случае связь многие ко многим, но ведб для этого нужно создаать связную таблицу, правильно. С другой стороны по имеющимся таблицам все будет работать правильно, но с точки зрения структуры таблиц выходит многие к одному (несколько детей у одного из родителей) или же одной записи из родителей соответствует несколь из студентов.
Все вроде понятно. но запутался в этом моменте. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас 2 поля, вот каждое из полей в отдельности и рассматривайте. И получаете многие (студенты) к одному (конкретному родителю). А вот если бы вы сделали таблицу id_студента - id_родителя и положили туда 2 записи было бы многие ко многим, но выглядело бы криво, потому как можно было бы положить сколько угодно записей для одного студента. Тогда бы потребовался справочник "типы родителей" и в нем два значения Отец и Мать и в таблице "Родители" добавили бы тип родителя и первичный ключ был бы id_студента-тип_родителя.

Comment: @Mike, целосообразнее сделать две отдельные таблици? Правильно я Вас понял? Я так и хотел сделть, но в одной из моих тем мне сказали, что создавать две таблици с в принципе одинаковіми полями ненужно

Comment: Две таблицы точно не нужны. А чем вам не нравится 2 поля в студенте ? Я бы их там оставил и все. Если конечно в дальнейшем не планируются Биологические/суррогатные/приемные/опекуны и т.п.

Comment: @Mike, прошу прощения за рассеяность или усталость. Все так и оставляю просто затупил.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо.

Comment: @Mike, прошу прощения за беспокойство, но никак не могу полностью разобратьться. Вроде понятно. а вроде и нет. Давайте сначала.

Comment: @Mike, мне необходимо, чтобы у студента было двое родителей, один или вообще ни одного. Если как Вы говорите рассматривать связи с точки зрения конкретного родителя, то да у него может быть несколько студентов. Но ведь родителей, как правило, двое. И если я правильно понимаю определение связей между таблицами, то оно и определяеться соотношением между их записями, и получается: ст №1 - син имеет род №1 - мама, род №2 - папа, тоже и у студента №2 - дочь. А мама имеет ст №1 и №2 как детей, отец тоже имеет двух детей.

Comment: @Mike, выходит связь многие ко многим, если одной записи соответствует несколько из другой таблици сущностей, и запись из второй таблици имеет несколько соответствий из первой. Вроде как для многие ко многим создается отдельная связная таблица. Это я вычитал в примерах в интернете, да и Вы мне говорили так. Ее здесь нету, но суть как бы таже. Или то что мы рассматриваем связь конкретной записи в таблице студентов не влияет на связи между таблицами + объясните Ваш пример про "тип родителя", как отдельное поле, зачем в том случае он нужен?

Comment: @Mike, то что я Вас пригрузил, понимаю, о чем и сожалею. Но с другой стороны действительно хотелось бы разобраться в мелочах, ведь запросы создать это одно, но структура БД, точнее ее понимание дело другое.

Comment: Вообще эти термины "многие ко многим", "многие к одному" это чисто теория. при проектировании БД о них никто не думает. Они не нужны. В идеале я бы тут назвал связь "два ко многим", только таких видов связи в теории нет :) А так у вас два поля, поля позволяют NULL значения, на случай если родителя нет. И в теории эти поля один-ко-многим

Comment: @Mike, выходит на практике с понятиями связей надо работать немного иначе?  Именно по этому я Вас и не понял сразу. Что еще раз доказывает, начколько полезна живая (хотя бы в переписке) консультация)

Comment: @Mike, последний вопрос и я Вас отпускаю. Вы говорите иногда нужны справочники как ограничители других полей других таблиц. Эти справочники - просто другие таблици, правильно я понял?

Comment: На практике вы понимаете, что у вас по условиям задачи может быть 0-2 родителя, причем один отец и одна мать (хотя в европе уже в документах собираются перестать разделять и писать родитель1, родитель2). Значит понимаете что два отдельных поля подойдут (с учетом NULL). все. точка. о названиях многие-одни не задумываемся. Если бы задача была 0 и более родственников/наставников - то понимаем, что в одном поле хранить нельзя, в родителе то же нельзя (студентов много) значит делаем связующую таблицу

Comment: А справочник да - отдельная таблица. Но опять же, если я понимаю что значения два и больше их ни при каких обстоятельствах быть не может, я могу не заводить справочников, а сделать значения 1,2 и может быть сделать check constraint на поле, который не позволит туда вносить ничего кроме 1 или 2. (правда не знаю есть ли они и работают ли они в MySQL) и включу это поле в уникальный ключ (студент-тип), таким образом внести две записи студент-отец будет невозможно. Если же я догадываюсь, что завтра могут появится опекуны и надо бы их различать, но пока их нет - тогда сделаю таблицу-справочник

Comment: @Mike, благодарю за Вас за понятное объяснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычная связь "один ко многим" по каждому из полей `m_id`, `f_id`. Если какого-то из родителей нет - соответствующее поле `NULL`

Выборка родителей студента

```
SELECT
  f.*,
  m.*
FROM
  students st
  LEFT JOIN parents f ON f.id = st.f_id
  LEFT JOIN parents m ON m.id = st.m_id
WHERE
  st.id = 333
```

Выборка детей родителя

```
SELECT
  st.*
FROM
  parents p
  LEFT JOIN students st ON (p.id = st.f_id OR m.id = st.m_id)
WHERE
  p.id = 333
```

Выборка братьев студента

```
SELECT
  sibl.*
FROM
  students st
  LEFT JOIN students sibl ON (sibl.f_id = st.f_id OR sibl.m_id = st.m_id)
WHERE
  st.id = 333
```

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ